# Using shader to move texel to its center

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl, shader

I'm trying to move squared texture texel to the center of the texture following time.
The following code is doing it's job unless I want the pixel drawn vanish when it reaches the center of the geometry (a plane) and for now it's only becoming more a more small while time increase and the texture seems to be like contracted.

[image]

```
uniform float time;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {

    vec2 center = vec2(0.5, 0.5);
    vec2 newPosition = vec2(vUv.x + t * (center.x - vUv.x), vUv.y + t * (center.y - vUv.y);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D( texture, vec2(newPosition.x, newPosition.y) );
}
```

***Edit :***

Think of this as a black hole in the texture center.
[image]

Comment: t is between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: t  is always increasing in the render loop:  (i.e t += 0.01  )

Comment: Then the disparity between `vUv.x` and `t * (center.x - vUv.x)` will continue to grow. At `t = 0.0` you have `(vUv.x, vUv.y)` and `t = 1.0` you have `(center.x, center.y)`. What you actually have here is `t * center - (1.0 - t) * vUv` - after `t > 1.0` for pixels left-of-center this value is positive and to the right-of-center it is negative, so rather than moving your texture you actually scale it (and in fact, also flip it). Have you tried using `vec2 (vUv.x + t * center.x, vUv.y + t * center.y)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I completely understand the problem with my approach. Yes I tried ```vec2 (vUv.x + t * center.x, vUv.y + t * center.y)``` and this actually make the texture move for top right corner to bottom left

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what you actually want here. Maybe if you drew a diagram with some arrows showing how the texture is supposed to move over time it would make things clearer?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, I just add a picture, hoping that makes it more clear :)

Comment: Do your magic in `vec2 newPosition` and then normalize the `newPosition`. If you're applying an offset to align in the center, then don't forget to divide the `newPosition` by half, before offsetting again.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want the texel to be at `vUv` when *`t=0`* and at `center` after a while.

The result is a zoom-in on the center of the texture.

Actually your code do it from `t = 0` to `t = 1`. When *`t = 1`* the texel position is `center`.

**You have the same behavior using the [mix](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mix.xhtml) function.**

```
vec2 newPosition = mix(vUv, center, t);
```

Also when *`t = 1`* **all** the texel are at `center` and the image is a single color image. (The color of the center of the texture).

Your problem is that `t` keep growing. And when `t > 1` the texel continues on their path. After they all meet at the center, now they stray from each other. The effect is that the texture is reversed and you see a zoom-out.

Depending on how you want it to end there are multiple solutions:

- You want to go to the maximal zoom and keep this image: [clamp](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/clamp.xhtml) *t* in the range `[0, 1]` like this `t = clamp(t, 0, 1);`.
- You want to go to the maximal zoom and the image vanish: stop to draw it when `t > 1` (or `t >= 1` if you do not want the single color image).
- You want an infinite zoom-in, *ie* texel going closer and closer to the center but never reach it.

For this third behavior, you can use a new `t`, say `t2`:

- `t2 = 1 - 1/(t*k+1);  // Where k > 0`
- `t2 = 1 - pow(k, -t); // Where k > 1`
- `t2 = f(t);      // Where f(0) = 0, f is increasing, continuous and limit in +∞ is 1`

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've faced the same issue. But I found alternative solution somewhere on Internet which is use tunnel shader instead of moving texture's texels to center. It has similar behaviour as you want.

```
float time = -u_time * 0.15;
vec2 p = 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / u_res.xy -1.0;
vec2 uv;

float a = atan(p.y,p.x);
float r = sqrt(dot(p,p));
uv.x = time+.1/r;
uv.y = a/3.1416;

vec4 bg = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: @socrateisabot, if you think it's useful, you should check it as answer!